# How to check in PHP that any values exist in array in addition to some fixed value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
$array = array('static_value_1', 'static_value_2', 'extra_value_1', 'extra_value_2');
```

How could I return true if any value exists in array in addition to static_value_1 and/or static_value_2?

For example this array should return true:

```
array = array('static_value_1', 'static_value_2', 'extra_value_1');
```

and this one false:

```
array = array('static_value_1', 'static_value_2');
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are static values ever present in array?

Comment: They might not always be present. It can be that none, only 1 or both are existing. So basically I need to find out if any value exist which key name is not static_value_1 or static_value_2.

Comment: Why don't you loop values and when a non static is present just return false...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think just looping looking for non-static should work:

```
function check_array($check) {
    $static=Array('static_value_1', 'static_value_2');
    // Dealing with empty array.
    if(count($check)==0) return false;

    foreach($check as $value) {
      // If value is not in static collection is an addition...
      if(!in_array($value, $static)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! That one helped me to solve the issue. Thanks!!!